# Oracle Scalar function in select vs table valued function join

Tags: oracle, plsql, performance

I have have a query that is performing poorly. One aspect of the query is the use of a cross join on a table-valued function, in all honestly I was mimicking my TSQL behaviors of using CROSS APPLY on a function to avoid using a scalar function call. Is this a bad behavior in Oracle?

The main issue I'm running into is that Oracle Tuning Advisor will not parse my query so I'm unable to research index optimizations yet. Normally I wouldn't post this much code but I suspect it is my query more than table optimization that may be causing an issue.

The statistics se table is really the only table with volumn more than 4,000,000 records.  Can anyone recommend the removal of blatant bad Oracle behaviors? Or if all looks well a good tool to get some index tuning advisory? The Oracle Enterprise Manager won't parse this query to provide any recommendations.

Additional Performance Information captured from trace and formatted
through TKPROF

> Parse: Count(1) | CPU(0.04) | Elapsed(0.04) | Disk(0) | Query(852) | Current(0) | Rows(0)
>
> Execute: Count(1) | CPU(0.00) | Elapsed(0.00) | Disk(0) | Query(0) | Current(0) | Rows(0)
>
> Fetch: Count(1) | CPU(9.64) | Elapsed(14.50) | Disk(34578) | Query(35610) | Current(4) | Rows(4)
>
> Misses in library cache during parse: 1 
>   Optimizer mode: ALL_ROWS
>   Parsing user id: 1165
>
> Rows     Row Source Operation
>
> ---
>
> ```
>   4  HASH JOIN OUTER (cr=38069 pr=34578 pw=0 time=19208475 us)
>   2   COLLECTION ITERATOR PICKLER FETCH REPORT_INTERVAL_SEQUENCE_UDF (cr=97 pr=0 >                                                                    pw=0 time=13766 us)
>   4   VIEW  (cr=37972 pr=34578 pw=0 time=19194353 us)
>   4    HASH GROUP BY (cr=37972 pr=34578 pw=0 time=19194329 us)
> ```
>
> 60650     FILTER  (cr=37972 pr=34578 pw=0 time=19673947 us)
>     60650      NESTED LOOPS  (cr=37972 pr=34578 pw=0 time=19431329 us)
>     60650       HASH JOIN  (cr=37941 pr=34578 pw=0 time=5294908 us)
>         4        COLLECTION ITERATOR PICKLER FETCH REPORT_MACHINEINFO_GETT_UDF (cr=2331 pr=0 pw=0 time=212033 us)
>     60650        TABLE ACCESS FULL ELS_STATISTIC_ENTRY (cr=35610 pr=34578 pw=0 
>                                                                      time=4416705 us)
>      60650       COLLECTION ITERATOR PICKLER FETCH REPORT_INTERVAL_GETT_UDF (cr=31 pr=0 >                                                                    pw=0 time=13372794 us)

```
SELECT
         TimeInterval,
         stats.During,
         stats.Name,
         stats.cnt
    FROM
        TABLE (GET_INTERVAL_SEQUENCE_UDF(
                                         TO_TIMESTAMP ('07/15/2011','mm/dd/yyyy')
                                        ,TO_TIMESTAMP ('07/20/2011','mm/dd/yyyy')
                                        ,2)) dtRange
    LEFT JOIN
    (
         SELECT
              i.During
              , mi.Name
              , SUM (CAST (VALUE_NUMERIC AS INT)) cnt

         FROM
              statistics se
         JOIN TABLE (Get_Context_Info_udf ()) mi 
              ON (se.Context_ID = mi.Context_ID)
         CROSS JOIN TABLE (Interval_GetT (se.EntryDate, 2)) i
         WHERE
              StatisticTypeID = HEXTORAW ('6CF933B091AE46FEA7F56BE96308190F') 
              AND EntryDate < TO_TIMESTAMP ('07/20/2011','mm/dd/yyyy') 
              AND EntryDate > TO_TIMESTAMP ('07/15/2011', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
         GROUP BY
             i.During
             , mi.Name
    ) stats ON dtRange.TimeInterval = stats.TimeInterval


The following are for reference in the aforementioned query.


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Interval_GetT(datestamp IN timestamp,  timeInterval IN int) 
RETURN TReportIntervalList AS vResult TReportIntervalList;
BEGIN
     SELECT TReportInterval(
                            CASE timeInterval 
                            WHEN 1 THEN TO_CHAR(datestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24') 
                            WHEN 2 THEN TO_CHAR(datestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
                            WHEN 3 THEN TO_CHAR(datestamp, 'YYYY-WW')
                            END
                           ) 
     BULK COLLECT INTO vResult                                       
     FROM Dual WHERE ROWNUM = 1;

     RETURN vResult;
END;



CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_INTERVAL_SEQUENCE_UDF(
      startTime IN timestamp,
      endTime IN timestamp,
      inputInterval IN int)
      RETURN t_interval_list_table   AS  intervalList t_interval_list_table := t_interval_list_table();
    BEGIN

    SELECT 
         CASE inputInterval
         WHEN 1 THEN (t_interval(REPORT_Interval_Get_udf((startTime + ((ROWNUM-1) * 1/24)), inputInterval))) --Hour
         WHEN 2 THEN (t_interval(REPORT_Interval_Get_udf((startTime + (ROWNUM-1)), inputInterval))) --Day
         WHEN 3 THEN (t_interval(REPORT_Interval_Get_udf((startTime + ((ROWNUM-1)*7)), inputInterval))) --Week
            END 
          BULK COLLECT INTO intervalList
          FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (CASE inputInterval 
                                          WHEN 1 THEN CAST(CEIL(((TRUNC(endTime, 'HH') - TRUNC(startTime, 'HH')) * 24)) AS INT)
                                          WHEN 2 THEN CAST(TRUNC(endTime, 'DD') - TRUNC(startTime, 'DD') AS INT)
                                          WHEN 3 THEN CAST(CEIL(((TRUNC(endTime, 'DD') - TRUNC(startTime, 'DD')) )/7) AS INT)
                                       END);
      RETURN intervalList; 

    END GET_INTERVAL_SEQUENCE_UDF;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION      Get_Context_Info_udf
    RETURN TTRFRMENGMACHINEINFOLIST AS vResult TTRFRMENGMACHINEINFOLIST;
    BEGIN    
        SELECT TTrfrmEngMachineInfo(ch.Context_ID, mac.Name)
        BULK COLLECT INTO vResult   
        FROM
            a ch  
        INNER JOIN
            b cxm  ON ch.CONTX_MACHINE_ID = cxm.CONTX_MACHINE_ID   
        INNER JOIN
            c mac ON cxm.MACHINE_ID = mac.MACHINE_ID   
        INNER JOIN
            d ic  ON mac.MACHINE_ID = ic.MACHINE_ID  
        WHERE 
            ic.ONFIGURABLE_ENTITY_ID =  HEXTORAW(Format_Guid_udf('11111111-FAE9-47A1-91A9-60A53E9660FE'))
            AND mac.IS_DELETED = 'N'
            AND ic.IS_DELETED = 'N';

        RETURN vResult; 
     END;
```

Comment: Next time, to help humans parse your question, please use paragraphs and proper punctuation. It helps our eyes index the text faster. And select the whole block of code you post then hit the `{}` button in the editor to make it pretty.

Comment: The tkprof mentions other names for your collections and functions than the rest of your post here. I don't know which tool you used to produce this output, but as it is now, it is hardly readable. Please use a direct copy-and-paste from tkprof. Also, the other queries in your tkprof file seem very relevant. If you use tkprof's sort parameter you can get them at the top of your file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can investigate where time is being spent and the execution plan Oracle chooses by following the advice in [this OTN thread](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=1812597)

Regards,
Rob.

Answer (score 2):

It all looks alien to me :)

Firstly, a SELECT FROM DUAL is unusual in PL/SQL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Interval_GetT(datestamp IN timestamp,  timeInterval IN int) 
RETURN TReportIntervalList AS vResult TReportIntervalList;
BEGIN
     SELECT TReportInterval(
              CASE timeInterval 
                     WHEN 1 THEN TO_CHAR(datestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24') 
                     WHEN 2 THEN TO_CHAR(datestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
                     WHEN 3 THEN TO_CHAR(datestamp, 'YYYY-WW')
              END) 
     BULK COLLECT INTO vResult                                       
     FROM Dual WHERE ROWNUM = 1;

     RETURN vResult;
END;
```

would be done as a simpler

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Interval_GetT(datestamp IN timestamp,  timeInterval IN int) 
RETURN TReportIntervalList;
BEGIN
  IF timeInterval  = 1 THEN
       RETURN TReportInterval(TO_CHAR(datestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24'));
  ELSIF timeInterval  = 2 THEN
       RETURN TReportInterval(TO_CHAR(datestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
  ELSIF timeInterval  = 3 THEN
       RETURN TReportInterval(TO_CHAR(datestamp, 'YYYY-WW'));
  ELSE
       RETURN NULL;
  END IF;
END;
```

Can't tell what TReportInterval does, so its hard to know what that module does.
I'd look at a PIPELINED PL/SQL function to replace GET_INTERVAL_SEQUENCE_UDF. The difficulty you will face with something like that is that the optimizer will never have a valid idea of how many rows it will return so it will often guess wrong.

A similar problem will arise with Get_Context_Info_udf. There's no obvious indication whether it will return 1 rows or 10,000. Again TTrfrmEngMachineInfo is totally opaque.

Bluntly, everything possible is being done to keep the optimizer ignorant of how to best action the query.

If the statistics table is the main one, I think you are filtering the table based on

```
 WHERE
      StatisticTypeID = HEXTORAW ('6CF933B091AE46FEA7F56BE96308190F') 
      AND EntryDate < TO_TIMESTAMP ('07/20/2011','mm/dd/yyyy') 
      AND EntryDate > TO_TIMESTAMP ('07/15/2011', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

summarising value_numeric based on Context_ID.

maybe some sort of summary across a date dimension (perhaps daily / weekly / monthly totals ?)

I'd try and get rid of as much PL/SQL as possible. Start with a simple query against statistics and describe what you want to do at each stage.

Comment: TReportInterval is the Type that the TReportIntervalList is defined for, that is why I did the select with case rather than IF...the statement you presented will not compile since the return type does not match the functions type.  The point in using the user defined type was to be able to use it as a CROSS APPLY (TSQL) and then be able to group on it to complete the statistics roll-up.